# Sending view model by ajax to controller - how does it really work?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-core

I can't understand why, sometimes sending object by ajax works and sometimes it doesn't. I have an example - everything happens in 1 view where I have 2 view components

**1st - view of view component**

```
@model ShippingViewModel

    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="@ShoppingCartHelper.TokenShipping" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="CustomerId" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LastName" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AddressNumber" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="AddressNumber" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="AddressNumber" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="City" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ZipCode" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="ZipCode" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="isTheSame">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="isTheSame">Czy dane płatnika mają być takie same jak dane wysyłki?</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" id="save-shipping">Dalej&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-level-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#save-shipping').on('click', function () {
            var ShippingViewModel = {
                CustomerId: $('input[name="CustomerId"]').val(),
                FirstName: $('input[name="FirstName"]').val(),
                LastName: $('input[name="LastName"]').val(),
                Email: $('input[name="Email"]').val(),
                Address: $('input[name="Address"]').val(),
                AddressNumber: $('input[name="AddressNumber"]').val(),
                City: $('input[name="City"]').val(),
                ZipCode: $('input[name="ZipCode"]').val(),
                IsTheSame: $('input[id="isTheSame"]').is(':checked'),
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/koszyk/cs',
                data: JSON.stringify(ShippingViewModel),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    if (xhr.status != 200) window.location.href = "/home/error/" + xhr.status;
                },
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    if (xhr.responseText.includes('@ShoppingCartHelper.TokenShipping')) {
                        $('#ShoppingCartCustomerShipping').html(xhr.responseText);
                    } else if (xhr.responseText.includes('@ShoppingCartHelper.TokenBilling')) {
                        $('#ShoppingCartCustomerShipping').hide();
                        $('#ShoppingCartCustomerBilling').html(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**1st - action in controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route(RouteUrl.ShoppingCart + "/cs")]
public IActionResult Shippping([FromBody] ShippingViewModel svm)
```

and above code works great - I'm receving `ShippingViewModel`

and then at the same view I have 2nd view component

**2nd - view of view component / the same approach**

```
@model BillingViewModel

    @if ((Model.BillingSteps != (int)CustomerModel.StepEnum.None) && (Model.BillingSteps == (int)CustomerModel.StepEnum.Shipping))
    {
        @Html.Raw("<div style=\"display:block;\">")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Raw("<div style=\"display:none;\">")
    }
    <input type="hidden" value="@ShoppingCartHelper.TokenBilling" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="BillingCustomerId" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BillingFirstName" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="BillingFirstName" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="BillingFirstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BillingLastName" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="BillingLastName" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="BillingLastName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BillingEmail" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="BillingEmail" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="BillingEmail" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BillingAddress" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="BillingAddress" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="BillingAddress" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BillingAddressNumber" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="BillingAddressNumber" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="BillingAddressNumber" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BillingCity" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="BillingCity" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="BillingCity" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BillingZipCode" class="m-1"></label>
        <div><span asp-validation-for="BillingZipCode" class="text-danger"></span></div>
        <input asp-for="BillingZipCode" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <button class="btn" id="save-billing">Dalej&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-level-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#save-billing').on('click', function () {
                var BillingViewModel = {
                    BillingCustomerId: $('input[name="BillingCustomerId"]').val(),
                    BillingFirstName: $('input[name="BillingFirstName"]').val(),
                    BillingLastName: $('input[name="BillingLastName"]').val(),
                    BillingEmail: $('input[name="BillingEmail"]').val(),
                    BillingAddress: $('input[name="BillingAddress"]').val(),
                    BillingAddressNumber: $('input[name="BillingAddressNumber"]').val(),
                    BillingCity: $('input[name="BillingCity"]').val(),
                    BillingZipCode: $('input[name="BillingZipCode"]').val(),
                };
                console.log(BillingViewModel);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/koszyk/cb',
                    data: JSON.stringify(BillingViewModel),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        if (xhr.status != 200) window.location.href = "/home/error/" + xhr.status;
                    },
                    complete: function (xhr) {
                        if (xhr.responseText.includes('@ShoppingCartHelper.TokenBilling')) {
                            $('#ShoppingCartCustomerBilling').html(xhr.responseText);
                        } else if (xhr.responseText.includes('@ShoppingCartHelper.TokenPayment')) {
                            $('#ShoppingCartCustomerBilling').hide();
                            $('#ShoppingCartCustomerPayment').html(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
```

**2nd - action in controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route(RouteUrl.ShoppingCart + "/cb")]
public IActionResult Billing([FromBody] BillingViewModel bvm)
```

and here - I'm receving `BillingViewModel - null`

and I dont understand `WHY` firt ajax call sending a model, and second dosent

I found a workaround - insted of `[FromBody] BillingViewModel bvm` I cound `[FromBody] object bvm`

and then I cound `deserialized bvm` - and its working

**Question**

What exacly I do wrong? it turns out that I don't understand how ajax works in asp core. I don't see any errors in my code.

**EDIT:**
**Model**

```
public int BillingCustomerId { get; set; }
public string BillingFirstName { get; set; }
public string BillingLastName { get; set; }
public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
public string BillingAddressNumber { get; set; }
public string BillingZipCode { get; set; }
public string BillingCity { get; set; }
public string BillingEmail { get; set; }
public int BillingSteps { get; set; }
```

**sending data**
[screen of sending data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD1Wl.png)

Comment: You tried check/comment ValidateAntiForgeryToken if it work without. This can stop  action.

Comment: yes - I tried it does not help

Comment: 1) Does you JavaScript function send a json request with a body that looks as expected? (see Browser > DevTools > Network - if yes, pls add an example that's not working to your question). 2) Is there anything your logs or in response body? 3) It seems you have a problem to read a json request to your model. It would help if we would know how your model looks like. 4) I think it does not help anyone if you include what's working, I'd suggest to remove the working example from your question.

Comment: I tested your original code and received BillingViewModel successfully . If you use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on the action, you should configure `services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");` in the configureservice of startup.cs and add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`  in your view. Could you share a simple and complete demo that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I have `services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");` at `ConfigureServices` in `public class Startup` and `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` at view that have those two view components

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me! - today, first of all, I removed all `DataAnnotations` (I didn't add them before to simplify the code for you) - and it works! BUT?! I need these `DataAnnotations` so I clean solution, rebuilt, add them one more time and its work again - in principle without any code edit